# WordPress Post Title + suffix

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have been looking for hours and I cant seem to find a solution, so was hoping some one here can help.

In wordpress when you have a post with the same title you get a number at the end of the post title for the url (/test, /test-2, /test-3). When I use the function get_the_title(); it only returns "test". I need a function that will return the post title and the -number.

Is there such function or is there a work around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save two posts with same post title. The number that adding to the post title was not actually title its postname. If you want to title with number then this will help you

```
global $post;

echo $post->post_name;


or


$sql = "select * from wp_posts where post_title='test';
$post = $wpdb->get_row($sql);

echo $post->post_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for isn't the title, it's the slug. It's found in the `$post` object.

```
<?php

  global $post;

  $slug = $post->post_name;

  $duplicate_number = array_pop( explode( '-', $slug ) );

?>
```

http://ideone.com/OS5bjA